# canvasに描画した内容を、予め指定した小さな形状の集まりに単純化することを何と呼ぶ？

Tags: 画像処理

下記リンク先で、マウスを使ってcanvasに線を引いた後、変換ボタンを押すと、その線に沿う形で、予め指定した小さな形状の集まりに単純化されるのですが、こういった(単純化する)動きをする実装を何と呼びますか？　(このようなことが出来る）ライブラリを探しているのですが、何のキーワードで検索したら良いか分からないので質問しました。
https://www.logoshi.com/draw-a-logo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご質問の「小さな形状の集まりに単純化」とか、参照先ツールの機能とは少し違いますが、Illustratorのブレンドツールやブラシツールのパスに沿って配置(Align to Path)が近いと思われます。

[パス(線)上にオブジェクト(図形)を等間隔に並べる方法【Illustrator】](https://www.yslife-b.com/archives/1696)

> 1. ブレンドを使う
>
> - オープンパス(パスが開いた線)の場合
> - クローズパス(パスが閉じた線)の場合
>
> 2. ブラシを使う
>
> - ブラシを使った簡単な方法
> - もっと均等にしたい場合

この動画が近い感じですね。
[How to Repeat a Shape Along Any Path in Adobe Illustrator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-0aSsuFGCY)

英語サイトの関連しそうな記事
[Distribute objects along a path in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/5044)

Illustratorの解説ページ
[ブレンドオブジェクトについて](https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/illustrator/using/blending-objects.html)
[ブラシについて](https://helpx.adobe.com/jp/illustrator/using/brushes.html)

Comment: (Illustratorを保持しているのですが、)今回はソフトウェアを使用せず、JavaScriptで処理してみたいです。「Align to Path canvas」で検索した内容を見て、パス操作すれば何とかなるかも、と思いました。

Answer (score 1):

単純化するステップは「量子化 (quantization)」でしょうか。

指定した形状の集まりにするステップに名前があるかどうかは存じません。